# How to put an arrow at midway of a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, edge

I am trying to reproduce the following figure:

[image: the picture I try to reproduce]

So far, my problem is to put the arrow of `c_{1}` at midway of the loop.

That is what I've already done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 70] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [decoration    = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with
  {\arrow[black,line width=0.5mm]{stealth'}}},
vertex/.style = {inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,draw,label={#1}},
edge/.style   = {postaction={decorate},thick}]
  \newcommand\R{2.7}
  \coordinate (A) at (0:\R);
  \coordinate (B) at (90:\R);
  \coordinate (C) at (180:\R);
  \coordinate (D) at (270:\R);
  \draw[edge] (C) -- (B) node[midway, left]{$a_{1}$};
  \draw[edge] (B) -- (A) node[midway, above]{$b_{1}$};
  \draw[edge] (A) -- (D) node[midway, right]{$a_{1}$};
  \draw[edge] (D) -- (C) node[midway, below]{$b_{1}$};
  \Loop[dir=WE,dist=3cm,label={$c_{1}$},labelstyle={left},style={
  ->,thick}](A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [decoration    = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with
  {\arrow[black,line width=0.5mm]{stealth'}}},
vertex/.style = {inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,draw,label={#1}},
edge/.style   = {postaction={decorate},thick}]
  \newcommand\R{2.7}
  \coordinate (A) at (0:\R);
  \coordinate (B) at (90:\R);
  \coordinate (C) at (180:\R);
  \coordinate (D) at (270:\R);
  \draw[edge] (C) -- (B) node[midway, left]{$a_{2}$};
  \draw[edge] (B) -- (A) node[midway, above]{$b_{2}$};
  \draw[edge] (A) -- (D) node[midway, right]{$a_{2}$};
  \draw[edge] (D) -- (C) node[midway, below]{$b_{2}$};
  \Loop[dir=EA,dist=3cm,label={$c_{2}$},labelstyle={right},style={
  ->,thick}](C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for including a minimal working document with your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify  `postaction={decorate}` on your `\Loop` command to place the arrow (and remove the `->` from the options, since you don't want the ending arrow.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 70] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [decoration    = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with
  {\arrow[black,line width=0.5mm]{stealth'}}},
vertex/.style = {inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,draw,label={#1}},
edge/.style   = {postaction={decorate},thick}]
  \newcommand\R{2.7}
  \coordinate (A) at (0:\R);
  \coordinate (B) at (90:\R);
  \coordinate (C) at (180:\R);
  \coordinate (D) at (270:\R);
  \draw[edge] (C) -- (B) node[midway, left]{$a_{1}$};
  \draw[edge] (B) -- (A) node[midway, above]{$b_{1}$};
  \draw[edge] (A) -- (D) node[midway, right]{$a_{1}$};
  \draw[edge] (D) -- (C) node[midway, below]{$b_{1}$};
  \Loop[dir=WE,dist=3cm,label={$c_{1}$},labelstyle={left},style={
  ,thick,postaction={decorate}}](A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]